# Why does a gap in my model change to a solid surface when switching to Object mode?

Tags: modeling, edit-mode

[image]

[image: object mode]

When I enter object mode, the space where I want the visor to be fills up and I was wondering If I render it that it will be filled up.

Comment: Yes. You have a portion of your object's mesh hidden in Edit Mode. In Edit Mode, hit Alt-H to see it again.

Comment: Ah thank you it worked but I don't remember hiding anything which is odd so I never tried pressing alt-h. Again thank you for helping me.

Comment: You must have clicked h to hide it